# Is there any way of creating different factories from the same resource with Factory Bot?

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a user factory like so:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { 'doo@d.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
    admin { true }
    confirmed_at Time.now
  end
end
```

which I use in my feature spec like so:

`user = create(:user)`

but I'd like to be able to have different parameters for different test cases. For example, I'd like a user factory with `admin { false }`. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Take a look at [traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use trait:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { 'doo@d.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
    admin { false }
    confirmed_at { Time.now }

    trait :admin do
      admin { true }
    end
  end
end
```

So `FactoryBot.create(:user)` is usual user and `FactoryBot.create(:user, :admin)` is admin

As you see in [README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-traits) you can use different traits simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried anything like this?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { 'doo@d.com' }
    password { 'password' }
    password_confirmation { 'password' }
    admin { false }
    confirmed_at Time.now

    factory :admin do 
      admin { true }
    end
  end
end

admin = create(:admin)
```